# Test coverage for multi module setup

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have three modules: `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` and `B` are not depending on any other module. Module `C` depends on `A` and `B`, to create a jar containing both artifacts.

```
components:   A   B
               \ /
application:    C
```

Can I run some integration tests on the application (created by module `C`) and then make JaCoCo calculate the test coverage over its components `A` and `B`?

```
components:   A   B  <= I want to see coverage in this code 
               \ /
application:    C    <= I want to run integration tests on this artefact
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in general - yes it is possible:

- By default JaCoCo agent collects information about execution of all the classes, no matter from where they come.
- Report generation requires collected information about execution, plus original class files and sources for which you want to generate report.

JaCoCo Ant Tasks provide great flexibility in specification of paths to all required files - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html